# Process Builder fails to deploy - field integrity exception

Tags: salesforcedx, process-builder, sfdx-error

I am trying to deploy a process builder using sfdx into production

I use this command to get the component:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Flow:myFlow
```

And use this command to deploy:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -c -m Flow:myFlow -l RunSpecifiedTests -r "notest"
```

And I always get this error:

> Error  myFlow field integrity exception

I cannot fix this no matter what I do

I have tried also to change all my hard coded Ids into labels from this post:

https://automationchampion.com/2017/04/21/getting-started-with-process-builder-part-66-how-to-fix-field_integrity_exception-error/

But it is not helping.

Other Process Builders are deployed successfully

Am I doing something wrong?

Is the Process builder bad?

Comment: what is the `sourceApiVersion` in your `sfdx-project.json`? Is this deploying a new process builder into production or an update to an existing one? Are there any new fields/invocable actions/email templates/etc you added that the process builder may be referencing that don't exist in production?

Comment: Thanks for your questions @KrisGoncalves, sourceApiVersion=53, deploying an updated existing PB to prod, and the only change is within a criteria of an existing field update

Answer (score -1):

I removed the record update element in the flow and it worked for me

Comment: This seems very specific to your situation, and OP doesn't mention any field updates. OP is also talking about Process Builder (which is deprecated) and not Flow (Visual Workflow)

Comment: Did you indeed get exactly the same error message "Error [flow name] field integrity exception"?!

Comment: Hi @FelixvanHove, Yes I was getting same error message "Error [flow name] field integrity exception"

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/210846)